# warning: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value

Tags: c++, c, gcc, warnings

The code is:

```
*(buf+2) |= (unsigned char)(mFlag & 0x7f);
```

`buf` is `unsigned char *` and `mFlag` is `unsigned char`

I guess it is because the return value of `operator|=` so that I get the warnings

> warning: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value

How can I remove the warning? Is it due to `operator|=`?

Comment: Did you try `buf[2] |= (unsigned char)(mFlag & 0x7f);`?

Comment: It's probably casting the result of the masking, which is an `int`. I don't see any particular use in this instance of the warning.

Comment: buf[2] also gives the warning. @Rapptz

Comment: For the result of masking, I coverted it to unsigned char, why it still hold an int value? And I did use the static_cast<unsigned char> as well ,not work either @chris.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, I don't get any warnings with `-Wall` and `-pedantic`. [Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c7202d1fd42bd407e60b8862b5e741f7-fcf98f666e0b68774061981371328429)

Comment: -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion
@Rapptz

Comment: @Rapptz, appears with `-Wconversion`

Comment: which is your version of gcc that gives this bogus warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C all arithmetic (including `&`) is done in types at least as wide as `int`. So the result of your expression will always be `int` or `unsigned` depending on the type of your constant.

Since the constant `0x7f` is obviously within bounds for any of the character types the warning your compiler gives is in effect not really helpful, I would even consider it a bug.

The only thing that you can do about this is

```
*(buf+2) = (unsigned)*(buf+2) | 0x7FU;
```

That is to convert the value explicitly to the wider type. If this still gives you a warning for the assignenent use

```
*(buf+2) = (unsigned char)((unsigned)*(buf+2) | 0x7FU);
```

but then you should definitively think of upgrading your compiler or change the warning options that you use.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that the integer promotion was forced for all arithmetic operands. But there it is in 6.3.1.1 just before paragraph 3.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the warning, you apparently need a temporary variable to hold the `0x7f` value.

```
unsigned char x = 0x7f;
*(buf+2) |= mFlag & x;
```

The problem seems to be that the compiler is treating any attempt to convert the literal to an `unsigned char` via a cast results in the warning (further discussion indicates this is specific to the `|=` operator, simple assignment does not seem to have a problem). However, initialization of a variable is allowed without warning.

Another workaround is to define an inline function to serve the same purpose as the cast. I made this function look similar to a C++ `static_cast<>`:

```
template <typename T>
inline T static_conversion (T x) { return x; }
//...
*(buf+2) |= mFlag & static_conversion<unsigned char>(0x7f);
```

A C version (which also works for C++) would use a different inline function, since C doesn't have templates:

```
inline unsigned char to_unsigned_char (unsigned char x) { return x; }
/* ... */
*(buf+2) |= mFlag & to_unsigned_char(0x7f);
```

Comment: That's not the problem, the result of `(mFlag & 127u)` is still an `int`

Comment: @DavidRF: It's not supposed to be.

Comment: Isn't it quite redundant expecially you have lots of masking work?

Comment: @user2612857: The inline function makes it less redundant, and about equivalent work as adding a cast.

Comment: Then I would prefer
*(buf+2) = static_cast<unsigned char>(*(buf+2) | (mFlag & 0x7f));

Comment: @user2612857: Hey, neat. Post that as an answer for yourself, and I'll up vote it.

Comment: Haha. New user is not allowed to answer its own question within 8 hour. Well, it still feels frustrated that "|=" can't be used

Comment: @user2612857: Not technically true, since I show two ways that would allow you to use it. But, I understand if you don't like the answer.

Comment: `*(buf+2) = (unsigned char)((mFlag & 0x7f) | *(buf+2));` compiles without warning and is C compatible

Comment: @jxh Yep, I agree that when there comes lots of masking work, the inline function is more proper. I'll think about which one to use for my case. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRF: Yes, I don't have an explanation as to why the `|=` operator is interfering with the ability to cast the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to get rid if the warning by declaring the constant as unsigned

```
*(buf+2) |= (mFlag & 0x7fu);
```

Comment: `warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]`

Comment: No the conversion in question is the one on the left side of `|=`.

Answer (score 0):

As @chris says, it's probably casting the result of the masking (and you get a warning when `-Wconversion` flag is on)

I would use `*(buf+2) = (unsigned char)((mFlag & 0x7f) | *(buf+2));` but if you insist on using `|=` you can take advantage of compound literals (only for C99):

```
*(buf+2) |= (unsigned char){mFlag & 0x7f};
```

Comment: No this wouldn't help, both operands are converted to `int` before the `|` operation.

Comment: @JensGustedt, have you tried running on C99? works for me without warning

Comment: This is not a question of C99 or not but of a buggy compiler that has bogus warnings. So probably neither you not me can test it without having the same version of gcc. Nevertheless, the conversion that that compiler complains about is on the left, I think.

Comment: A compound literal is a postfix expression that provides an unnamed object of the type specified in the cast whose value is given by the initializer list, works like `*(buf+2) |= dummy_unsigned_char = (unsigned char)(mFlag & 0x7f);`, keep in mind that `dummy_unsigned_char = (unsigned char)(mFlag & 0x7f);` is executed before than `*(buf+2) |= dummy_unsigned_char` and simple assignment doesn't seems to have problems, anyway you are right, its a bogus warning

Comment: A compound literal doesn't help at all here. Any "narrow" type is promoted to `int` (or sometimes `unsigned`) before arithmetic operations. There is no difference in how one obtains the expression of type `unsigned char`.

Comment: well ... helps because is skipping `-Wconversion` warning using `|=` (what the OP wants) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily disable this warning as follows:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
*(buf+2) |= (mFlag & 0x7fu);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```